# View page is locked/disabled after closing Bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

This problem is driving me crazy now. Here is the sequence and code I am doing:

I am using Backbone (Chaplin) JS, jQuery and Handlebars

1. Display a table with multiple rows in the view which is rendered via Handlebar template
2. Launch a Bootstrap modal dialog from the page
3. Fill some information, click the "Save" button on the modal dialog.
4. In the button click handler function, insert the record for a table row to model data something like:

   this.model.tabledata.push(new_record);

   this.render();
5. Call render to refresh the view with updated model data

Result and Problem:

- The table is refreshed with the new record
- The modal dialog is disappeared
- The view is LOCKED like greyed out and does not respond to click anymore.

What is the issue and how to fix? Please help!

Comment: "greyed out" out seems like the overlay part of the modal dialog. That is behind the modal dialog istself. So seems like the modal dialog is closed but not completely.

Comment: Where is the code how to fix?

Comment: Thank you very much, guys. Great comments and I will try them and let you know how I find out. To clarify, step 3 and 4 are done inside a button event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. I found, that bootstrap on modal show create a div-layer with a class "modal-backdrop". so if you want to return to the page and enable the page again do the following:

- hide the modal with: `$('#modalId').modal('hide');`
- remove the div layer: `$(".modal-backdrop").remove();`

I hope this answer helps

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out a way to fix my problem. The code is as following:

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    _this.render();
})
```

Basically I need to wait for the dialog completely closed before rendering the parent view page. Not sure exactly why but this works. Hopefully somebody can help answer. I guess this has something to do with fired event sequence.